# Logstash unable to assign value from json

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Given the following input:

111.111.111.111, 11.11.11.11 - 11.11.11.11 [06/May/2016:08:26:10 +0000] "POST /some-service/GetSomething HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" "7979798797979799" 59.370 - "{\x0A\x22correlationId\x22 : \x22TestCorr1\x22\x0A}"

with Logstash configuration:

```
input { stdin {} }
output { stdout { codec => "rubydebug" } }

filter {
   grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG} %{QS:partner_id} %{NUMBER:req_time} %{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}" }
     add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
     add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
   }


   mutate {
     gsub => ["extra_fields", "\\x0A","","extra_fields", "\\x22",'\"']
   }

   json {
     source => "extra_fields"
     target => "extra_fields_json"
   }


    mutate {
      add_field => {
        "correlationId" => "%{[extra_fields_json][correlationId]}"
      }
   }
}
```

Gave us the following output:

```
 
Logstash startup completed
{
                   "message" => "111.111.111.111, 11.11.11.11 - 11.11.11.11 [06/May/2016:08:26:10 +0000] "POST /some-service/GetSomething HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" "8888888" 59.370 - "{\x0A\x22correlationId\x22 : \x22TestCorr1\x22\x0A}",
                  "@version" => "1",
                "@timestamp" => "2016-06-23T18:00:28.831Z",               
                  "clientip" => "11.11.11.11",
                     "ident" => "-",
                      "auth" => "10.0.12.205",
                 "timestamp" => "06/May/2016:08:26:10 +0000",
                      "verb" => "POST",
                   "request" => "/some-service/GetSomething",
               "httpversion" => "1.1",
                  "response" => "499",
                     "bytes" => "0",
                  "referrer" => "\"-\"",
                     "agent" => "\"Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1\"",
                "partner_id" => "\"8888888\"",
                  "req_time" => [
                      [0] "59.370",
                      [1] "1"
                   ],
              "extra_fields" => "\"{\\\"correlationId\\\" : \\\"TestCorr_1\\\"}\"",
             "extra_fields_json" => "{\"correlationId\" : \"TestCorr_1\"}",
                "correlationId" => "correlationId"

}
Logstash shutdown completed
```

Why value of  "correlationId" is "correlationId" rather than "TestCorr_1\" ???

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the extra `"` and `\` from `extra_fields` for the json to be parsed correctly. 
You would have to change your mutate filter to :

```
mutate {
      gsub => ["extra_fields", "\"","",
          "extra_fields", "\\x0A","",
          "extra_fields", "\\x22",'\"',
          "extra_fields", "(\\)",""
      ]
 }
```

Don't hesitate to give feedback if it works/doesn't work

Comment: Amazing... it works! Thanks a lot I have been spending days to fix this. BTW one more question, if the json is empty, it shows the text, how can I make it blank if the source does not have the field,                         "correlationId" => "%{[extra_fields_json][correlationId]}" , should be                      "correlationId" => ""  if the field does not present in the source.

Comment: I think you'll have to use sthg like this, after the json filter : if ([correlationId] == "%{[extra_fields_json][correlationId]}") {...} with the mutate filter and the replace option on the correlationId field ([doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-replace))

Comment: Hi @yanto  if the answer has solved your question please consider accepting it. If you need further help do not hesitate to comment/ask a new question